# Hide video when clicked on any other element but itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am loading a video in the DOM using a directive named `load-video` when the `displayVideo` property is `true`.

```
  <figure id = "positionVideo" ng-show = "displayVideo">
    <load-video></load-video>
  </figure>
```

loadVideo directive:

```
 angular.module('homePage')
          .directive('loadVideo', function($document, $window) {
            return {
              restrict: 'E',
              templateUrl: 'partials/video/video.html',

              link: function(scope, element) {
                element.data('loadVideo',true);

                angular.element($document[0].body).on('click',function(e) {
                  var inElem =  angular.element(e.target).inheritedData('loadVideo');
                  if (inElem) {
                    scope.displayVideo = true;
                  } else {
                    scope.displayVideo = false;
                  }
               })
             }
           };
          });
```

video.html

```
<video height = "50%" width = "150%"  id = "playVideo" ng-click="playIt()" poster = "images/eagle.jpg" controls>
          <source src = "images/lion.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
 </video>
```

The `figure` tag has access to this controller:

```
angular.module('homePage').controller('watchVideo',  ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.displayVideo = false;

    $scope.videoAvailable = function () {
      $scope.displayVideo = true;
    };

    $scope.closeVideo = function() {
        $scope.displayVideo = false;
    };

    $scope.playIt = function() {
        if (jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).paused) {
            jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).play();
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();
        }
    }
}]);
```

I do not understand why the `video` element is not hiding when I am changing the `displayVideo` property to `false`.

I am providing my entire application below for context:

```
<div class="firstView" ng-controller = "watchVideo"> 
      <figure class="logo" ng-controller = "logo" ng-click="goToUrl('/home')"> </figure>

      <cite>Every brand has a story.</cite>
      <h2 id = "h2Heading"> <a ng-click = "videoAvailable()">Watch the video </a></h2>
      <aside> &#x2192; </aside>

      <figure id = "positionVideo" ng-show = "displayVideo">
        <load-video></load-video>
      </figure>

      <summary ng-controller = "buttonViewCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-hide = "buttonDisplay" ng-show = "!displayVideo" class="btn btn-default btn-lg navButton" aria-label="Center Align"  ng-click="nav()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" id = "closeButton" ng-show = "buttonDisplay" ng-hide = "!displayVideo" ng-click = "closeNav(); closeVideo()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>

        <div ng-show = "buttonDisplay" id = "buttonDisplayContent" class = "cssFade">
          <navigate></navigate>
        </div>
    </summary>

    <main ng-controller="ScrollCtrl">
      <div id = "arrow">
        <img src = "images/pointer.png" alt = "arrow" ng-click="gotoElement('panda')">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "panda" id = "panda">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg work"> SEE OUR WORK </button>
    </div>
    <main>

    <div class = "experience">
      <h1> Our team builds great brands and experiences. </h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg team"> MEET THE TEAM </button>
    </div>

    <section class = "about">
      <h5> WHAT ARE WE? </h5>
      <h2> Anchour is a branding agency based in Maine. </h3>

      <p> We weave together creative solutions to build personal brands and experiences. We work closely with your brand to understand your needs and create solutions that produce real results. By integrating the power of identity, digital, and sensory design, we bring new life to brands everywhere.
      </p>
    </section>

    <div class = "goodWork">
      <div class = "spotlight"> 
        <h3> <a href = "#"> Spotlight: Amanda Brill of Las Vegas </a> </h3>
        <p> Amanda Brill is a Designer at Anchour. Fueled by the purpose of helping others, she works to bring the identity of a brand to life through a creative and intensive design process. to help brands effectively communicate who they she works to bring the identity of a brand to life through a creative... </p>
        <footer> <a href = "#"> Read More </a> </footer>
      </div>

      <div class = "spotlight"> 
        <h3> <a href = "#"> Spotlight: Amanda Brill of California </a> </h3>
        <p> Amanda Brill is a Designer at Anchour. Fueled by the purpose of helping others, she works to bring the identity of a brand to life through a creative and intensive design process. Her goal is to use design as a way to help brands effectively communicate who they sponsor and supporter Fueled by the purpose of.. </p>
        <footer> <a href = "#"> Read More </a> </footer>
      </div>

      <div class = "spotlight"> 
        <h3> <a href = "#"> Varney Agency: Protecting What You </a> </h3>
        <p> Anchour produced Varney Agencys latest spot featuring Matt Albrecht, owner of River Drive. Working with companies from all around the world, River Drive buys, sells, reconditions and recycles reconditions and ecycles owner of used. River Drive buys, sells Varney Agencys latest spot featuring Matt Albrecht.</p>
        <footer> <a href = "#"> Read More </a> </footer>
      </div>

      <div class = "spotlight"> 
        <h3> <a href = "#">Announcing support of Not Here </a> </h3>
        <p> This week is Human Trafficking Awareness Week, so it’s great timing to share how proud we are to be a sponsor and supporter of Not Here latest spot featuring Matt Albrecht, reconditions and recycles owner of River Drive. Working with companies from all around the,a River Drive buys, sells.... </p>
        <footer> <a href = "#"> Read More </a> </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "start">
      <h2 id = "startWork"> Want to work with us? </h2>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> Get Started &#x2192; </button>
    </div>

    <div id = "end">
      <footer>
        <a href = "#/home"> Home </a>
        <a href = "#"> About us </a>
        <a href = "#"> Our Team </a>
        <a href = "#"> Blog </a>
        <a href = "#"> Services </a>
        <a href = "#"> Portfolio </a>
        <a href = "#"> Contact </a>
        <a href = "#"> Sitemap </a>
    </footer>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is not hiding because Angular doesn't know that the model has changed. In fact, `element.on()` is just the plain old jQuery `on` function, it isn't Angular-aware.

You may have noticed that the video disappears when you click outside then inside it : that's because the `ng-click` handler, which gets fired first being the innermost listener, triggers the digest phase for you, causing `ng-hide` to update the view.

The proper way to handle this is `$scope.$apply()` :

```
var body = angular.element($document[0].body);
body.on('click',function(e) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        var inElem = angular.element(e.target).inheritedData('loadVideo');
        console.log(inElem);
        if (inElem) {
            scope.displayVideo = true;
        } else {
            scope.displayVideo = false;
            jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();
        }
    });
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kad81ksy/5/).

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but it hasn't solved the problem. Your fiddle is not closing the video when clicked outside it.

Comment: You can only click on a tiny area on the sides of the video, there is not much space left for the `body` element. Try decreasing the width of the video template.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The video disappears, but I can still hear the audio. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Well, just do `jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();` when you set `displayVideo` to false.

Comment: It is still not working. You have altered the `displayVideo` property's default value to be `true`, and that is why it is working in the fiddle. I need it to be `false` when the page loads.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle one more time. `displayVideo` is set to false at start. Notice the ` $event.stopPropagation()` call when you click on the "Watch the video" header.